# ¿Como habilitar y deshabilitar botones en Jframe form?

Tags: java, mysql

lo que necesito es mostrar los datos de una jtable y cuando  se muestren los datos aparezcan tres botones. en ese momento quiero que el botón "NUEVO" este habilitado y los botones  "ACTUALIZAR" y "ELIMINAR" estén deshabilitados...

luego de esto quiero seleccionar una fila y los botones aparezcan en un estado diferente osea  "NUEVO" este deshabilitado y "ACTUALIZAR" y "ELIMINAR" ahora estén habilitados....
dejo el código del método mostrar datos

espero me puedan entender  y seguramente me puedan ayudar..

```
//método mostrar auto

public void mostrarAuto(){
        String[] titulos = {"ID", "Placa","Marca", "Modelo","Color"};
        String [] registros = new String[6];
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM automovil";

        try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL);
            while (rs.next()) {
                registros[0]=rs.getString("id_auto");
                registros[1]=rs.getString("placa");
                registros[2]=rs.getString("marca");
                registros[3]=rs.getString("modelo");
                registros[4]=rs.getString("color");

                modelo.addRow(registros);
            }
            tablaAutomovil.setModel(modelo);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error de datos"+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esto es Java no JavaScript, tu etiqueta esta mal seleccionada.

Comment: Para desactivar: `tu_jbutton.setEnabled(false);`. Para activar `tu_jbutton.setEnabled(true);`. Luego eso lo administras con un `table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener`

Comment: Gracias, ese es el método. Pero lo que necesito es que curandero seleccione  una fila se habiliten automáticamente unos botones y se deshabilite otro